# Can I create Azure resources from ARM templates in C# code using supported libraries?

Tags: c#, azure

I have some C# code that creates Azure resources from ARM templates using the **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent** NuGet packages. I use an object of type **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.IAzure** and do approximately this:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
    .WithSubscription(subscriptionId)
    .Deployments
    .Define(deploymentName)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
    .WithTemplate(armTemplateAsString)
    .WithParameters(parameters)
    .WithMode(mode)
    .CreateAsync(ct)
```

Visual Studio tells me that the **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent** NuGet packages are deprecated and that I should use the **Azure.ResourceManager** ones instead.

Is there a way to deploy resources from ARM packages in C# code using the **Azure.ResourceManager** NuGet packages or other supported libraries?

(I suppose I can call the `az` command line tool from C#, but that is very ugly. I would prefer something nicer.)

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-deploy-using-arm-template